# Fetching blob type image in laravel blade file

Tags: laravel-5, blob, wampserver, laravel-blade

I have inserted the image to the table directly from backend using wampp server. The image is stored in blob type in the table.
I'm not able to fetch the image into front end . I'm using laravel 5.2 can you please  suggest me with correct code to be used in my blade file. I'm completely new to laravel.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

    <p><img src="{{ $user->logo }}" alt="logo.png"></p>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: Show us how you store the row. How you get it back depends on what you did to it when you stored it

Answer (score 0):

I am see you problem you can try to decode blob file using `base64_decode($file)`
this function.

Comment: where to use this function .

Comment: <img src="{{ base64_decode($user->logo) }}" alt="logo.png"></p>